# Make returns `mpif90: No such file or directory`

Tags: makefile, fortran, mpi, gfortran

I'm trying to work with a program that a physicist wrote. I'm on a MacOS, and I've downloaded all the programs and libraries that I was told was necessary for the program to compile and run (GCC, MPI, using the version of MAKE that is already on Macs). I opened the makefile, and I was told to write

```
F90 = mpif90
```

and then compile the program using

```
make IO=txt
```

but I get this message:

```
mpif90 -g -O3 -c mod_input.f90 
make: mpif90: No such file or directory
make: *** [mod_input.o] Error 1
```

I have no idea what this means, and what to do to get this to work.

Comment: If you installed Fortran mpi  support  for a  mpi which uses that name, you haven't  set up the paths.  Other  mpi implementations use names such as mpifort .

Comment: Why mpif90? Did you verify that mpif90 exist as an executable in your computer?

Comment: You mentioned that "someone told me to write..." Who was that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3492

This article describes how to get, install and configure MPI (Open MPI flavor) at macOS. After installing it, you should get mpif90 as well.